# EnsureMember in pallet-collective

Tags: pallet-collective

I'm getting issue when implementing EnsureMember of pallet-collective. I have implemented pallet-collective like this:

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const TechnicalMotionDuration: BlockNumber = 5 * DAYS;
    pub const TechnicalMaxProposals: u32 = 100;
    pub const TechnicalMaxMembers: u32 = 100;
}

type ManagerCollective = pallet_collective::Instance2;

impl pallet_collective::Config<ManagerCollective> for Runtime {
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type Proposal = RuntimeCall;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type MotionDuration = TechnicalMotionDuration;
    type MaxProposals = TechnicalMaxProposals;
    type MaxMembers = TechnicalMaxMembers;
    type DefaultVote = pallet_collective::PrimeDefaultVote;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_collective::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

impl pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
    type ManagerOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureMember<AccountId, ManagerCollective>;
}
```

I have set Alice and Bob are ManagerOrigin. It is the return data of Managers

```
managerCommittee.members: Vec<AccountId32>
[
  5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
  5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty
]
```

But when I call the `do_something` function with Alice I can't pass this check and getting BadOrigin error.

```
T::ManagerOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)?;
```

Did I miss something? Alice should call `do_something` function without any error right?

Comment: Could you give more detail?

What's the `EnsureMember`? What's the `ManagerCollective`?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier EnsureMember is a struct of pallet_collective https://docs.rs/pallet-collective/latest/pallet_collective/index.html. I updated the question.

Comment: I also have the same problem. could you tell me how you solve it and what do you mean by "call is from origin not specific account"?. I am not sure what you mean by origin. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `pallet_collective::EnsureMember` implementation expects `pallet_collective::RawOrigin::Member(who = Alice)` origin, not a `Signed(Alice)`.
This probably what you missing. You can get such an origin when you execute for example via `pallet_collective::execute` call.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. I must call this from an origin instead of from a specific account.